# creating an array from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm using a array to get a range between 1011-2371 but I'didnt need all digits. It's a long list thats why I import the CSV to the database.

I want to create a array from a database table. 
But I can't get it.

Here's a rough mockup of the old php:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
    <input type="text" placeholder="1234AB" name="postcode" />
    <input type="submit" value="verstuur" />
</form>
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $postcode = range(1011,2371);
    if(preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]{3} ?[a-zA-Z]{2}$/', $_POST['postcode'])) {
        if(in_array($_POST['postcode'],$postcode)) {
            echo 'FreshFoods is beschikbaar bij jou in de buurt.';
        } else {
            echo  'FreshFoods is nog niet beschikbaar bij u in de buurt.';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Voer 4 cijfers en 2 letters in als postcode. Voorbeeld 1234AB';
    }
}
?>
```

and this is what I try do get the array from the database:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
    <input type="text" placeholder="1234AB" name="postcode" />
    <input type="submit" value="verstuur" />
</form>
<?php
require_once 'db_config.php'; 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $postcode = array();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT postcode FROM postcode_check");

    if(preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]{3} ?[a-zA-Z]{2}$/', $_POST['postcode'])) {
        if(in_array($_POST['postcode'],$postcode)) {
            echo 'FreshFoods is beschikbaar bij jou in de buurt.';
        } else {
            echo  'FreshFoods is nog niet beschikbaar bij u in de buurt.';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Voer 4 cijfers en 2 letters in als postcode. Voorbeeld 1234AB';
    }
}
?>
```

the db_config.php file looks like:

```
<?php 
$db = array ( 
    'host' => 'localhost', 
    'user' => 'root', 
    'pass' => 'root', 
    'dbname' => 'testzip' 
); 

if(!mysql_connect($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass'])) 
{ 
    trigger_error('Fout bij verbinden: '.mysql_error()); 
} 
elseif(!mysql_select_db($db['dbname'])) 
{ 
    trigger_error('Fout bij selecteren database: '.mysql_error()); 
} 
else 
{ 
    $sql = "SET SESSION sql_mode = 'ANSI,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'"; 
    if(!mysql_query($sql)) 
    { 
        trigger_error('MySQL in ANSI niet mogelijk'); 
    } 
} 
?>
```

Comment: You need to fetch the result then store it in `$postcode`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: So you have a query (`$result = ...`) but you don't fetch/execute it. Moreover, you don't use the results in your code.

Comment: @chris85 I tried but don't get the right message :(

Comment: Look at my answer and message..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc` to fetch the result from database.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
<input type="text" placeholder="1234AB" name="postcode" />
<input type="submit" value="verstuur" />
</form>
<?php
require_once 'db_config.php'; 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
$postcode = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT postcode FROM postcode_check");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $postcode[] = $row['postcode'];
}
if(preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]{3} ?[a-zA-Z]{2}$/', $_POST['postcode'])) {
    if(in_array($_POST['postcode'],$postcode)) {
        echo 'FreshFoods is beschikbaar bij jou in de buurt.';
    } else {
        echo  'FreshFoods is nog niet beschikbaar bij u in de buurt.';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Voer 4 cijfers en 2 letters in als postcode. Voorbeeld 1234AB';
}
}
?>
```

Try this code.

Comment: change the  `$postcode[] = $row;` to  ` $postcode[] = $row['postcode'];`

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch the result. Your regex will never match your sample data from the db though so you will always get the nog niet message. or voorbeeld. Never 'FreshFoods is beschikbaar bij jou in de buurt'

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
    <input type="text" placeholder="1234AB" name="postcode" />
    <input type="submit" value="verstuur" />
</form>
<?php
require_once 'db_config.php';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $postcode = array();
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT postcode FROM postcode_check");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $postcode[] = $row['postcode'];
    }
    if(preg_match('/^[1-9][0-9]{3} ?[a-zA-Z]{2}$/', $_POST['postcode'])) {
        if(in_array($_POST['postcode'],$postcode)) {
            echo 'FreshFoods is beschikbaar bij jou in de buurt.';
        } else {
            echo  'FreshFoods is nog niet beschikbaar bij u in de buurt.';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Voer 4 cijfers en 2 letters in als postcode. Voorbeeld 1234AB';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks @chris85, this is what I want. I wil focus now on the fetch process

Comment: Any particular reason this was reverted from being the answer?